# Why does selenium Python script run really slow in cron compared to vscode

Tags: python, cron

When I run a script through vscode it takes about 3s per loop where as cron takes 8-9.
macOS. Simple selenium Python script just finding elements and clicking. Same interpreter. I don’t know what to try. Apple silicon if it matters

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late.

**Problem:**

Running a python script with crontab in the background caused very slow performance (MacOs, M1 Sillicon)

**My Solution:**

Run the bash script, open a terminal and run the python script.

Here an example.

Run the script every day at 4 PM

```bash
crontab -e
```

```bash
00 16 * * * path/to/the/bash_script.sh
```

Then, create your bash_script.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Open a new terminal window and run the Python script
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "python python_script.py"'
```

Finally, apply permissions:

```bash
chmod +x bash_script.sh
```

Comment: Works well. Any idea why this happens?